# Select items matching the names and those with the same category

Tags: php, mysql, database

I don't know how to word this problem so i'll just show you guys what i need.

I have a table like this:

```
+----+----------------+------------+
| id |      name      |    med     |
+----+----------------+------------+
|  1 | seclo          | omeprazole |
|  2 | something else | other      |
|  3 | ometid         | omeprazole |
+----+----------------+------------+
```

and until now i have been using the following query to get the records.

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE (name LIKE '%{$search}%' OR med LIKE '%{$search}%')
```

but now i want to search for the name (or the med) and want the records which has the same med as the ones matching the name.

Like if I put "sec" i want record 1 and 3 because record 3 has the same med as which matches record 1.

i hope the question is clear.
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will help you

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE med IN (SELECT med from item WHERE name LIKE '%{$search}%' OR med LIKE '%{$search}%')
```

Comment: I was trying to come up with a join solution, but this really seems much cleaner +1.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a subquery that refer the same table to get the `med` needed:

```
SELECT * 
FROM item 
WHERE med in (
    SELECT med 
    FROM item 
    WHERE (name LIKE '%{$search}%' OR med LIKE '%{$search}%')
OR name LIKE '%{$search}%')
```

Comment: Thank Man! Worked like a charm!

Comment: i think you missed a parenthesis the the end.

Comment: @MohammedSharfuddinShawon yes, I've just added it

Answer (score 0):

// try this ..

```
SELECT * FROM `item` WHERE `med` IN (SELECT `med` FROM `item` WHERE (`name` LIKE '%{$search}%' OR `med` LIKE '%{$search}%') OR `name` LIKE '%{$search}%')
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited short-term help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.